# bash script not interpreting commands

Tags: bash, unix

I am writing a simple bash script (I am fairly new to bash). I am trying to assign the output of a command to a variable and I can't seem to get it to work properly. See below:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=`hostname`
MEMORY=`prtconf -v |grep Memory |awk '{print $3}'`
echo "os_instance_name "$HOST
echo "physical_machine_ram "$MEMORY
```

I am able to get the result of `hostname` properly but my `MEMORY` variable is not being populated with the output from the command.

Comment: What's the output of `prtconf -v |grep Memory |awk '{print $3}'`?

Comment: does the command `prtconf -v |grep Memory |awk '{print $3}'` work when entered by itself?

Comment: it is the ram in megabytes ex. 4096

Comment: Try a basic `MEMORY=$(prtconf -v)` and then `echo $MEMORY`. This way you will see if it is a problem when calling `prtconf`.

Comment: step by step debugging.

Comment: BTW, grep|awk is silly: `prtconf -v|awk '/Memory/ {print $3}'` is all you need.

Comment: Does prtconf send its output to stderr? try `prtconf -v 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @glennjackman - if so, wouldn't it bypass `grep` and `awk`?

Comment: it seems to be working now using @Jens command. thanks for the help

Comment: @Floris, yes, but the reported problem was that the variable did not have a value with no other details. A variable assignment will only take stdout from a backtick-ed command.

Comment: @glennjackman - I thought the same thing but he said that the same command at the command line gave the right response. Which made me think the output of `prtconf` was being further processed by `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
memory=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}'`

echo $memory
```

should return the physical memory in megabytes

Also, `$1` in the code that you have provided might be referring to a blank column. Try using `$2`.

Comment: My guess (based on the `prtconf` command) is that this is on a Solaris system, which doesn't have `free`, at least not by default. Not sure if SunFreeware or some other source provides it...

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas spring to my mind:

1. execute the script in debug mode

   ```
   $ bash -x myscript.sh
   ```
2. Put the variable expansions within the double quotes

   ```
   echo "os_instance_name $HOST"
   echo "physical_machine_ram $MEMORY"
   ```